# Characters Loop

Tags: java, loops, numbers, character

How can I make a for *loop or other type of loop* based on characters too? For example **0 - z** , than **1a - 1z** , than **2a - 2z** , etc

Thanks !

Comment: What exactly is your problem and what have you tried?

Comment: all variables names can be characters... where is the problem?

Comment: You can count to characters if that is your question. Just write something like `i < 'a'` into your loop and let it run.

Comment: I was trying to make a loop that runs throughout the alphabet and numbers to guess what is the word.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main ()
    {
       // for loop execution
       for( int a = 'a'; a < 'z'; a++ )
       {
           cout << "value of a: " << a << endl;
       }

       return 0;
    }
```

in C++, for other language ask me in comment.

Answer (score 0):

You would write the "normal" int-based for loop but instead of your counter being of type **int**, it would be of type **char**:

```
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c) {
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

This works because chars are integers represented as characters. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is the encoding telling java which number what character represents. This for loop is basically the same as this:

```
for (int i = 97; i <= 122; ++i) {
    char c = (char)i;
    System.out.println(c);
}
```